# Data in power query won't refresh with new data in my Power Pivot table

Tags: powerquery, powerpivot

My Power Query in excel won't update the data from my Power Pivot table in the same excel file

I have an excel file that use data from several sources.

One source is a Power Pivot table that i got from Exporting data from powerbi.com to analysis in excel.

I want to use the data from the power pivot table and transform the data in power query in my excel sheet. In power query, I have created a query from the sheet with the power pivot table.

The data in the Power Pivot table sheet is updated with new data when i refresh data, but the power query won't refresh with the new data from the power pivot table sheet. How can I get the power query data to refresh with the new data from the power pivot sheet..

Does anyone understand my question and know why?

Kind regards,
Cecilia

Comment: What is the Source (first step) of the powerquery (from home ... advanced editor)?  Is that step referring to the refreshed power pivot table sheet?

Comment: Yes, the first step of the powerquery is referring to the refreshed power pivot table sheet in the excel file.